# To get the data into list

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, foreach, xelement

I have 2 list as below,

```
List<object>[] data = new List<object>[4];
List<HMData>[] Data_Content = new List<HMData>[7];
int indexer=0;

And also I have 3 list as LValues,IValues and BValues each containing 28 data values as follows

LValues={L1,L2,L3....L28},
IValues={I1,I2,I3...I28},
BValues={B1,B2,B3....B28},

foreach (var item in Read_xml_for_childobjects_id.Root.Descendants("object")) //  Contains 4 Items
  {
 for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
     {
       Data_Content[k] = new List<HMData>();
       Value_LfromList = LValues.ElementAt(k);
       Value_IfromList = IValues.ElementAt(k);
       Value_BfromList = BValues.ElementAt(k);

       Data_Content[k].Add(new HMData { x = Value_LfromList, y = Value_IfromList, z = Value_BfromList });
      }   
      data[indexer] = new List<object>(Data_Content);
      indexer++;
  }
```

now I want the output to be as follows,

```
data=[{L1,I1,B1},{L2,I2,B2},{L3,I3,B3},{L4,L4,B4},{L5,I5,B5},{L6,I6,B6},{L7,I7,B7}],
data=[{L8,I8,B8},{L9,I9,B9},{L10,I10,B10},{L11,I11,B11},{L12,I12,B12},{L13,I13,B13},{L14,I14,B14}],
data=[{L15,I15,B15},{L16,I16,B16},{L17,I17,B17},{L18,I18,B18},{L19,I19,B19},{L20,I20,B20},{L21,I21,B21}],
data=[{L22,I22,B22},{L23,I23,B23},{L24,I24,B24},{L25,I25,B25},{L26,I26,B26},{L27,I27,B27}{L28,I28,B28}].
```

Now if in for loop for k,if I take condition as `for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)` then I get output as follows,

```
data=[{L1,I1,B1},{L2,I2,B2}.....{L7,I7,B7}],
data=[{L1,I1,B1},{L2,I2,B2}.....{L7,I7,B7}],
data=[{L1,I1,B1},{L2,I2,B2}.....{L7,I7,B7}],
data=[{L1,I1,B1},{L2,I2,B2}.....{L7,I7,B7}],
```

Since it encounters only first 7 elements of list each time the loop runs

And if I take for loop as for `(int k = 0; k < 28; k++)`,since I have total 28 elements in each list, then after Data_Content list is filled with 7 elements since this is what I wanted and when 8 element is encountered then I get an error as

```
Index was outside of bounds of the array..
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, I know I have placed two more questions on same problem but I doubt I was not able to explain my problem properly, I hope this question is clear,

-------updated question-------

```
 for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
  {
    for (int l = 0; l < 7; l++)
     { 
       Value_LfromList = LValues.ElementAt((k * 7) + l);
       Value_IfromList = IValues.ElementAt((k * 7) + l);
       Value_BfromList = BValues.ElementAt((k * 7) + l);
       Data_Content.Add(new HMData { x = Value_LfromList, y = Value_IfromList, z = Value_BfromList });
            }
        data.Add(Data_Content);
      }
   }

   var data_List = new { data = data };
   var series = new[] { data_List };
   var obj = new {chart,series };
   string result = jSearializer.Serialize(obj);
```

so the output I get is as follows,

```
{"chart":{"type":"bubble"},
 "series":
   [
      {"data":
         [
           {"x":7,"y":7,"z":49},{"x":7,"y":7,"z":49},{"x":7,"y":9,"z":63},
           {"x":5,"y":9,"z":45},{"x":4,"y":3,"z":12},{"x":2,"y":6,"z":12},
           {"x":3,"y":5,"z":15},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},
           {"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":9,"y":6,"z":54},{"x":5,"y":7,"z":35},
           {"x":3,"y":8,"z":24},{"x":4,"y":3,"z":12},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},
           {"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":8,"y":7,"z":56},
           {"x":5,"y":7,"z":35},{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":5,"y":8,"z":40},
           {"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":5,"y":2,"z":10},
           {"x":5,"y":2,"z":10},{"x":8,"y":6,"z":48},{"x":7,"y":3,"z":21},
           {"x":6,"y":7,"z":42}
         ]
      }
   ]
 }
```

now output I want is as follows,

```
{"chart":{"type":"bubble"},
 "series":
   [
      {"data":
         [
           {"x":7,"y":7,"z":49},{"x":7,"y":7,"z":49},{"x":7,"y":9,"z":63},
           {"x":5,"y":9,"z":45},{"x":4,"y":3,"z":12},{"x":2,"y":6,"z":12},
           {"x":3,"y":5,"z":15}],

        "data":
         [
           {"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},
           {"x":9,"y":6,"z":54},{"x":5,"y":7,"z":35},{"x":3,"y":8,"z":24},
           {"x":4,"y":3,"z":12}],

        "data":
         [
           {"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},
           {"x":8,"y":7,"z":56},{"x":5,"y":7,"z":35},{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},
           {"x":5,"y":8,"z":40}],

         "data":
         [
           {"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":5,"y":2,"z":10},
           {"x":5,"y":2,"z":10},{"x":8,"y":6,"z":48},{"x":7,"y":3,"z":21},
           {"x":6,"y":7,"z":42}
         ]
      }
   ]
 }..
```

I have to convert data I am getting into JSON format to plot graph and also data tag is mandatory...I hope I explain you...

-------Updated question-------

```
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
  {
    List<HMData> Data_Content = new List<HMData>();
    for (int l = 0; l < 7; l++)
     {
       Value_LfromList = LValues.ElementAt((k * 7) + l);
       Value_IfromList = IValues.ElementAt((k * 7) + l);
       Value_BfromList = BValues.ElementAt((k * 7) + l);
       Data_Content.Add(new HMData { x = Value_LfromList, y = Value_IfromList, z = Value_BfromList });
     }
     data_list.Add(Data_Content);
   } 
   var chart = new
    {
      type = ChartType
    };
   var data = new { data = data_list };
   var series = new[] { data };
   var obj = new {chart,series };
   string result = jSearializer.Serialize(obj);
```

and this is my output

```
{"chart":{"type":"bubble"},"series":[{"data":[[{"x":7,"y":7,"z":49},
{"x":7,"y":7,"z":49},{"x":7,"y":9,"z":63},{"x":5,"y":9,"z":45},{"x":4,"y":3,"z":12},
 {"x":2,"y":6,"z":12},{"x":3,"y":5,"z":15}],
[{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},
 {"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":9,"y":6,"z":54},{"x":5,"y":7,"z":35},{"x":3,"y":8,"z":24},
 {"x":4,"y":3,"z":12}],
[{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},
 {"x":8,"y":7,"z":56},{"x":5,"y":7,"z":35},{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":5,"y":8,"z":40}],
[{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":5,"y":2,"z":10},{"x":5,"y":2,"z":10},
 {"x":8,"y":6,"z":48},{"x":7,"y":3,"z":21},{"x":6,"y":7,"z":42}]]}]}
```

--------Updated Required output-------

```
{"chart":{"type":"bubble"},"series":[
{"data":[[{"x":7,"y":7,"z":49},
{"x":7,"y":7,"z":49},{"x":7,"y":9,"z":63},{"x":5,"y":9,"z":45},{"x":4,"y":3,"z":12},
 {"x":2,"y":6,"z":12},{"x":3,"y":5,"z":15}],

 "data":[{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},
 {"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":9,"y":6,"z":54},{"x":5,"y":7,"z":35},{"x":3,"y":8,"z":24},
 {"x":4,"y":3,"z":12}],


  "data":[{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},{"x":7,"y":8,"z":56},
 {"x":8,"y":7,"z":56},{"x":5,"y":7,"z":35},{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":5,"y":8,"z":40}],


  "data":[{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":3,"y":7,"z":21},{"x":5,"y":2,"z":10},{"x":5,"y":2,"z":10},
 {"x":8,"y":6,"z":48},{"x":7,"y":3,"z":21},{"x":6,"y":7,"z":42}]]}]}
```

I want **data** word to come with every data list in json output... which is not coming....

Comment: List<HMData>[] Data_Content = new List<HMData>[7]; is declared with a length of 7, so it can't be longer ?

Comment: I know,My ultimate goal is to have data list which contains 4 data_content list each containing 7 elements and not the same first 7 elements since my list from where I take data values contains in total 28 values each..

Comment: I have clearly mentioned in question what I want and how I am doing..if question is not clear then please let me know,I will change the question, I just want to know How I can do to get desired output...???

Comment: You are using foreach but not using item ? (i'm just pointing at what is not clear in your example...)

Comment: Item is an xelement and I need to parse it into int value to pass to data[indexer] = new List<object>(Data_Content); this stmt, so have made used of int indexer intitialized to 0 and then incremented the indexer on each loop increment in foreach.

Comment: Try using next statement at the right time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654113/how-do-i-skip-an-iteration-of-a-foreach-loop ?

Comment: how that continue keyword is going to help me since I am struggling with for loop, I am not able to get proper set of 4 data list each containing 7 elements according to its position in their respective list...???

Comment: And basically I don't want to skip any iteration since my foreach loop gives me 4 id's and so I want to make 4 data list each containing data_content list holding 7 elements..

Comment: @jon skeet.. can you look at this question, I think I have explained my problem well here,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is only psudo code and will not work.
However, I think this is what you are trying to do and provided a working example.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<List<HMData>> data = new List<List<HMData>>();

        string[] Ls =
        {
            "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L7", "L8", "L9", "L10", "L11", "L12", "L13", "L14",
            "L15", "L16", "L17", "L18", "L19", "L20", "L21", "L22", "L23", "L24", "L25", "L26", "L27", "L28"
        };
        string[] Is =
        {
            "I1", "I2", "I3", "I4", "I5", "I6", "I7", "I8", "I9", "I10", "I11", "I12", "I13", "I14",
            "I15", "I16", "I17", "I18", "I19", "I20", "I21", "I22", "I23", "I24", "I25", "I26", "I27", "I28"
        };
        string[] Bs =
        {
            "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "B9", "B10", "B11", "B12", "B13", "B14",
            "B15", "B16", "B17", "B18", "B19", "B20", "B21", "B22", "B23", "B24", "B25", "B26", "B27", "B28"
        };

        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            List<HMData> Data_Content = new List<HMData>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                var l = Ls.ElementAt((k*7) + j);
                var i = Is.ElementAt((k*7) + j);
                var b = Bs.ElementAt((k*7) + j);

                Data_Content.Add(new HMData {x = l, y = i, z = b});
            }

            data.Add(Data_Content);
        }

        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            Console.Write("data=[");
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0},",item[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0}]", item[6]);

        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}


public class HMData
{
    public string x;
    public string y;
    public string z;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{{{0},{1},{2}}}", x, y, z);
    }
}
```

The output is:
[image: run example]

------------------------------- EDIT FOR OP ----------------------------------
Note your code needs to have this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
{
    List<HMData> Data_Content = new List<HMData>();
    ....
}
```

as i've said in the comments

Comment: inside the j loop when when the j value is 1 while second turn I get an error while adding data to Data_content list as Object reference not set  to an instance of an object...can you please check and tell whats wrong there..thank you...

Comment: sorry bout that. fixed it.

Comment: Your code is working with one problem..in first data list,I get output as data=[{l1,i1,b1},{l2,i2,b2},{l3,i3,b3}...{l7,i7,b7},null,null,null,null,null,null] and in second data list , data of first list is also added like data=[{l1,i1,b1},{l2,i2,b2}....{l7,i7,b7},{l8,i8,b8}...{l14,i14,b14},null,null,null,null,null] and third data=[{l1,i1,b1},{l2,i2,b2}....{l7,i7,b7},{l8,i8,b8}...{l14,i14,b14}....{l21,i21,b21},null,null,null,null] and last data=[{l1,i1,b1},{l2,i2,b2}....{l7,i7,b7},{l8,i8,b8}...{l14,i14,b14}....{l21,i21,b21}......{l28,i28,b28},null,null,null]..can you fix this

Comment: my example does not do that. I think in your code you will need to push List<HMData> Data_Content = new List<HMData>() to the beginning of the first loop. Or are you still using a size 28 index... ?

Comment: problem is I am getting all the 28 element in one data list as data=[{l1,i1,b1}...{l28,i28,b28}]...whereas I want 4 different data list so that I can plot 4 different series in graph..i want to get data as [data=[{l1,i1,b1}...{l7,i7,b7}],data=[{l8,i8,b8}...{l14,i14,b14}],data=[{l15,i15,b15}...{l21,i21,b21}],data=[{l22,i22,b22}...{l28,i28,b28}]]...i hope u understand

Comment: how can I add the values of data_content to the array of data with 4 size?

Comment: actually...c I will paste my entire code for your clarification in above question, have a look at it..

Comment: I have that, I have just declare the data_Content list outside the loop ..does it create problem to define it outside the for loop?

Comment: yes because you keep adding data to it. so you get one Content_Data with 28 elements. Instead of 4 different ones each containing 7 elements.

Comment: still getting the same result,sorry..but dont know whats going wrong..all data values in one single data

Comment: var data = new { data = data_list };
 var series = new[] { data };.....this is what I am finally building the stmt..is it the source of problem

Comment: One thing I noticed is I get 4 data_list contained in 4 square bracket shown in output above,just not getting tag name as data against the respective array of data's

Comment: whats the problem with the out put? you have a list containint 4 lists of 7 elements... this is what you asked for is it not?

Comment: the problem is with the JSON serialization. you are setting var data = new { data = data_list }; which generates 1 data: [4 elements of the data_list]. I'm not that fluent in JSON serialization. Seems like i answered your question and now you need to ask a new question about JSON serialization. hope this helps.

Comment: sure..thanks a lot..well you have really helped me a lottt...Thanks from bottom of my heart...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on Linq operators rather than explicit iteration. It uses the Batch operator from the [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) project - it's available on NuGet.

The line to zip the L, I and B-value sequences together is a little ugly, but .NET doesn't have a built in 3-argument sequence zip (zip got added in .NET 4.0, an alternative implementation is in MoreLinq for earlier versions). I'd probably implement my own extension method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using MoreLinq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public class HMData     // Dummy HMDta class for test purposes
        {
            public string x { get; set; }
            public string y { get; set; }
            public string z { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inputItems = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; // Input items from XML document - dummy test list

            // L, I and B value sequences
            var LValues = new List<string>() { "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L7", "L8", "L9", "L10", "L11", "L12", "L13", "L14", "L15", "L16", "L17", "L18", "L19", "L20", "L21", "L22", "L23", "L24", "L25", "L26", "L27", "L28" };
            var IValues = new List<string>() { "I1", "I2", "I3", "I4", "I5", "I6", "I7", "I8", "I9", "I10", "I11", "I12", "I13", "I14", "I15", "I16", "I17", "I18", "I19", "I20", "I21", "I22", "I23", "I24", "I25", "I26", "I27", "I28" };
            var BValues = new List<string>() { "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "B9", "B10", "B11", "B12", "B13", "B14", "B15", "B16", "B17", "B18", "B19", "B20", "B21", "B22", "B23", "B24", "B25", "B26", "B27", "B28" };

            // Convert our 3 -value sequences into one sequence of HMData objects
            var zippedValues = LValues.Zip(IValues, (lvalue, bvalue) => Tuple.Create(lvalue, bvalue)).Zip(BValues, (pair, bvalue) => new HMData() { x = pair.Item1, y = pair.Item2, z = bvalue });

            // Split the sequence into length of length 7
            var batchedValues = zippedValues.Batch(7);

            // For each of the inputItems, output a batch from the -value sequences
            // (note we will stop output as soon as either the inputItems or the combined -value sequences are exhausted)
            var data = inputItems.Zip(batchedValues, (item, valueBatch) => valueBatch).ToArray();

        }
    }
}
```