# Getting HTML response fails respectively after first fail

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, webrequest, httpwebresponse

I have a program which gets html code for ~500 webpages every 5 minutes

it runs correctly until first fail(unable to download source in 6 seconds)

after that all threads will fail

and if I restart program, again it runs correctly until ...

where I'm wrong, what I should do to do it better?

this function runs every 5 mins:

```
        foreach (Company company in companies)
        {
            string link = company.GetLink();

            Thread t = new Thread(() => F(company, link));
            t.Start();
            if (!t.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6)))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine( company.Name + " Fails");
                t.Abort();
            }
        }
```

and this function download html code

```
private void F(Company company, string link)
    {
        try
        {
            string htmlCode = GetInformationFromWeb.GetHtmlRequest(link);
            company.HtmlCode = htmlCode;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

and this class:

```
public class GetInformationFromWeb
{
    public static string GetHtmlRequest(string url)
    {
        using (MyWebClient client = new MyWebClient())
        {
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(url);
            return htmlCode;
        }
    }
}
```

and web client class

```
public class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception returned?

Comment: @Legends there are many "thread abort exception" in output

Comment: you can use `Continue` in your catch block, refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654113/how-do-i-skip-an-iteration-of-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 1):

IF your foreach is looping over 500 companies, and each is creating a new thread, it could be that your internet speed could become a bottleneck and you will receive timeouts over 6 seconds, and fail very often.

I suggest you to try with parallelism. Note `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, which sets maximum amount of parallel executions. You can tune this to suit your needs.

```
 Parallel.ForEach(companies, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, (company) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    string htmlCode = GetInformationFromWeb.GetHtmlRequest(company.link);
                    company.HtmlCode = htmlCode;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    //ignore or process exception
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have four basic suggestions:

1. Use `HttpClient` instead of obsolete `WebClient`. `HttpClient` can deal with asynchronous operations natively and has far more flexibility to take advantage of. You can even read downloaded contents to strings/streams on different thread since you can configure `await` not to schedule back your operations. Or even program the `HttpClientHandler` to break after 6 seconds and raise `TaskCanceledException` if this was exceeded.
2. Avoid swallowing exceptions (like you do in your `F` function) as it breaks debugging and obfuscates the real cause of problems. Correctly-written program will never raise an exception during normal operation.
3. You are using threads in an useless way, in which they are not even overlapping; they are just waiting for each other to start, because you are locking the calling loop after each thread's start. In .NET it would be better to do multitasking using `Task`s (for example, by calling them as `Task.Run(async delegate() { await yourTask(); })` (or `AsyncContext.Run(...)` if you need UI access) and it won't block anything.
4. The whole `GetInformationFromWeb` class is pointless in the moment - and you are spawning multiple client objects also pointlessly, since one HTTP client object can handle multiple requests (if you'd use `HttpClient` even without additional bloat - you just instantiate it once as static global variable with all necessary configuration and then call it from any place using as little code as `client.GetStringAsync(Uri uri)`.

OT: Is it some kind of an academic project?